# Queues in RabbitMQ Management are not displayed

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, .net-6.0, rabbitmq-management

I am stuck with the following problem:

I am trying to use .Net 6/C# with RabbitMQ by using RabbitMQ.Client library.

1. I use docker to get the container of RabbitMQ. The following command is applied:

   ```
   docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name ecomm-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
   ```
2. Write the following code to create the queue and add a message:

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Producer is begining its work...");
   var factory = new ConnectionFactory
   {
       HostName = "localhost",
       Port = 5672,
       UserName = "guest",
       Password = "guest",
       VirtualHost = "/"
   };

   using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
   using var channel = connection.CreateModel();


   var queueName = "demo-queue";
   channel.QueueDeclare(queueName,
       durable: true,
       exclusive: false,
       autoDelete: false,
       arguments: null);

   var message = new Message { Name = "Producer", Description = "Hello!" };
   var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

   channel.BasicPublish("", queueName, null, body);

   Console.WriteLine("The message was sent successfully");
   ```
3. Open RabbitMQ management http://localhost:15672/ enter guest credentials. And I cannot find any info about created queue:
   [image]

Any ideas why I cannot find the queue? I defenitly know that the queue was created and the message was pushed to the queue, because I am able to consume this message. The guest has administration role.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you report. I see the queue in the management interface. Please see the code I used, and a screenshot of the queue here: https://github.com/lukebakken/stackoverflow-76335193-queues-in-rabbitmq-management-are-not-displayed/tree/main